# github organization, repository and user access

Tags: git, github

Consider the case where an organization has a repository with two branches, `master` and `1.0.0.1`, for example.

Is it possible to have a team read-only access to `master`, however read-write access to the branch (`1.0.0.1`)?

Comment: I don't know the answer for certain so I'm just going to leave this comment. Until very recently I thought the answer was no. There was a very recent feature called "protected branches" which allows you to make branches which require a status api check to pass (like unit tests or something) in order for a change to be merged. If you are willing to write some code I would expect you could make a program that hooks into the status API and control merging to master on whatever terms you like. Otherwise I don't know a way. https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks

Comment: This is antithetical to Git. The intended and supported workflow would be for the team to clone the repository and issue pull requests against the main repo, where somebody with write access could choose to accept or reject them.

Answer (score 1):

Since March 2016, **Organizations can now specify which members and teams are able to push to a protected branch**.

See "[Protected Branches Improvements](https://github.com/blog/2137-protected-branches-improvements)"

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4719/14140705/ed98abac-f67a-11e5-951e-b48c842fb77f.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Github's new feature of [Protected Branch](https://help.github.com/articles/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/).

[image]

Enable **Require status checks to pass before merging** will make `master` branch read-only, and all writes to this branch need a PR. You can control the permission in the PR with a [status checks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) service, like Travis CI.